# Regex shows different return different result at the same time

Tags: java, regex, string

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Validate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Matcher matcher;
        Pattern regex;
        String str="David";
        regex =Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        matcher= regex.matcher(str);
        System.out.println("First result="+matcher.find());  //true
        System.out.println("Second result="+matcher.find()); //false

    }
}
```

Comment: Your first call to `Matcher#find()` consumes the entire input, so the second call fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API documentation of Matcher.find()

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a
>   previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
>   not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the
>   previous match.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.

So, for the code to run you have to call `Matcher.reset()` before calling `Matcher.find()` again.